# What exactly is a module in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I am absolutly new in **AngularJS** and I am finding some difficulties trying to understand how exactly it implement the MVC pattern.

So I have this first doubt related to this example in which I have 2 files:

1) **index.htm**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to AngularJS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                font-size: 1.1em;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <!-- This div and its content is the view associated to the 'mainController': -->
            <div ng-controller="mainController">

                <h1>Hello world!</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

2) **app.js** file:

```
/* MODULE: one signgle object in the global namespace.
           Everything indise the element having ng-app="angularApp" custom attribute is connected to the angularApp variable into the
           global namespace
*/
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);

// CONTROLLERS
angularApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

I am finding some difficulties trying to identify who is the **MODEL**, who is the **CONTROLLER** and who is the **VIEW**.

So it seems to me to understand that **ng-app="angularApp"** attribute defined on the html tag:

```
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">
```

bind the entire **index.htm** page to the **angularApp** variable

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);
```

So what exactly represent the **angularApp** variable? Is it an Angular **module**? and what exactly represent a module in Angular?

Comment: I've only got minimal experience with Angular myself, but as I understand it, the module performs the role of the controller in the MVC pattern.  And within the module are "models" for each of the dynamic elements in the view.  Those are declared like this `$scope.PropertyA = blah;` or maybe a function instead of a value.

Comment: @Nick So I can say that the $scope object is something similar to a model object (POJO) of a Java MVC application?

Comment: I can't really answer that with authority because I have no Java experience.

Comment: $scope isn't a POJO, because it isn't. It contains a bunch of scope-specific stuff besides model properties. You can figure it out by logging it or checking $rootScope docs.

Comment: If you want to learn by example i recommend the modular angular demo of John Papa (https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/modular/src/client/app). You can learn a lot from how he structures his project and its modules. It's a sample app implementing the famous styleguide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide by the same author. The demo completely changed my mind of whether and how the use of more than a single module in an app is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide. There is also a very nice tutorial that answers all your questions https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

Ultimately, I found that there is no way around it. AngularJs is a complex framework and it has a steep learning curve.

---

`<html lang="en-us" ng-app="angularApp">` says that the content of `<html>` tag is controlled by `angularApp` app but index.html is not the `view` as you may think. You should think about `view` as a template that comes with `directive`s (i.e. Angular components).

A quick recap of Angular concepts is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

> Module - a container for the different parts of an app including
> controllers, services, filters, directives which configures the
> Injector
>
> View - what the user sees (the DOM)
>
> Controller - the business logic behind views

Answer (score 2):

From the [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org) documentation

> What is a Module? You can think of a module as a container for the
>   different parts of your app – controllers, services, filters,
>   directives, etc.
>
> Why? Most applications have a main method that instantiates and wires
>   together the different parts of the application.
>
> Angular apps don't have a main method. Instead modules declaratively
>   specify how an application should be bootstrapped. There are several
>   advantages to this approach:
>
> The declarative process is easier to understand. You can package code
>   as reusable modules. The modules can be loaded in any order (or even
>   in parallel) because modules delay execution. Unit tests only have to
>   load relevant modules, which keeps them fast. End-to-end tests can use
>   modules to override configuration.

that being said a Module is an app within your app.. in your module you can have controllers and models..

Answer (score 1):

To Understand Angularjs, you must not stay only in the MVC pattern, with angular you can use this pattern but it's more MV*, Model View Whatever you need.

so the variable angularApp contains angularApp module with all his dependencies, controllers, providers, services etc..., a module can be a Part or the Whole application it's up to you.